# Is adding Flask env vars to the virtualenv's activate script OK?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I'm working on my Flask project in a virtualenv. Every time I start a new terminal, I have to reinitialize these Flask environment variables:

```
export FLASK_APP="server.py"
export FLASK_DEBUG="1"
```

My goal is to not have to type them in manually.

I tried writing a Python script that set them, but couldn't make it work. I tried writing a shell script that set them, but Flask would raise an error that said my Python path was incorrect.

Finally, I tried adding the the env vars to the bottom of the virtualenv's `activate` script. It worked! The env vars are set and Flask runs as expected.

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ flask run
```

Is it OK to modify the `activate` script like this? This is just for development purposes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, setting environment variables in the virtualenv's `activate` script is fine for managing your development environment. [It's described in Flask's docs.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/cli/#environment-variables-from-virtualenv) They're only active when the env is activated in the terminal, and you have to remember to add them if you create a new env, but there's nothing wrong with it.

---

With Flask 1.0, you can [use dotenv files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/cli/#environment-variables-from-dotenv) instead. Install python-dotenv:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Add a `.flaskenv` file:

```
FLASK_APP=server
```

And the `flask` command will automatically set them when running a command:

```
flask run
```

The advantage of this over messing with the venv is that you can commit this file so it applies anywhere you work on the code.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying `venv/bin/activate` file is working for you because the environment variable is getting defined inside the virtual environment. When you're using `python3 -m venv venv` the environment variables are not present in the new virtual environment. Instead of modifying the `activate` file, you can instead make a shell script which:

1. Runs `venv/bin/activate`
2. Defines the environment variables
3. Runs the server

> First, I tried writing a Python script that set them, but after research, I realized it was not possible(?).

You could use `os.environ` to do the same from within, but a shell script is better.